# thread pool example in "Concurrency in Action"

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, threadpool

The book *Concurrency in Action* gives examples of how thread pools can be implemented in C++11.

Here is Listing 9.3 (p. 279), which shows how a thread pool (implemented a few pages earlier) can be used:

```
template<typename Iterator,typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first,Iterator last,T init)
{
    unsigned long const length=std::distance(first,last);

    if(!length)
        return init;

    unsigned long const block_size=25;
    unsigned long const num_blocks=(length+block_size-1)/block_size;

    std::vector<std::future<T> > futures(num_blocks-1);
    thread_pool pool;

    Iterator block_start=first;
    for(unsigned long i=0;i<(num_blocks-1);++i)
    {
        Iterator block_end=block_start;
        std::advance(block_end,block_size);
        futures[i]=pool.submit(accumulate_block<Iterator,T>());
        block_start=block_end;
    }
    T last_result=accumulate_block<Iterator,T>()(block_start,last);
    T result=init;
    for(unsigned long i=0;i<(num_blocks-1);++i)
    {
        result+=futures[i].get();
    }
    result += last_result;
    return result;
}
```

Here, we have a number of futures stored in a vector. Each future is the result of submitting a task to the thread pool. However, when a task is created (in the first for loop), only a functor (`accumulate_block`) is provided, not the arguments (`block_start` and `block_end`):

```
        futures[i]=pool.submit(accumulate_block<Iterator,T>());
```

How can this work? Where do the tasks get their arguments from?

PS - the source code is available online: https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code lacks something, however this is not very important. Looking at the definition of `accumulate_block`:

```
template<typename Iterator,typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
    T operator()(Iterator first,Iterator last)
    {
        return std::accumulate(first,last,T());
    }
};
```

we see that block_start and block_end should be supplied somehow into `pool.submit` call. Here is how it can be implemented:

```
futures[i]=pool.submit([block_start, block_end]()
{
    accumulate_block<Iterator,T> a();
    return a(block_start, block_end);
});
```

The class `thread_pool` may also require some changes.

Comment: +1 for use of lambda... can also be done with std::bind, as in this implementation https://github.com/huangfeidian/ThreadPool/blob/master/ResultPool.h#L137